# Creating web socket server on Azure hosting using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket

I have a node application I am trying to host on Azure, that create a websocket server.  I am trying to create the web socket server using the code below:

```
var socket = require('websocket').server;
...
server.listen(1111,function(){
   console.log('Http server is listening on port 1111');
});
```

When I do this on my local machine it works fine, but once it's up on Azure the following line of client side javascript:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws:' + document.domain + ':1111');
connection.send(msg); //throws error
```

Throws the error:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not,
>   or is no longer, usable

Can I get the desired functionality if I'm using azure?  If so, any suggestions on where to start looking for a fix?

You can see the broken app in action [here](http://chatfeeder.azurewebsites.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work on Azure, but you need to make a change.  Try this:

```
server.listen(process.env.port, function () {
  var addr = app.address();
  console.log('Server listening on http://' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
});
```

Here's a tutorial on using the chat example from Socket.IO's source in Azure:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/app-using-socketio/

It assumes you're on Windows, which isn't strictly necessary.  To use Node.js on Azure from a Mac or Linux system, just publish from Git:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/

Comment: Hrrm, do you know where console.log writes to?  I looked around in my FTP directory but didn't see anything in there.  I'm trying to update the client side of my application so that it can use the correct port, but I need to see what gets logged when it starts listening to do that.